# How to enable Paint Bucket instead of Material Drop Tool on CC 2015?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools, cc-2015

I'm using photoshop CC 2015 and I can't select Paint bucket anymore, only this annoying Material Drop Tool is shown instead of bucket in the Tools.

any ideas?

[image]

Comment: It should be easy to change between **Material Drop Tool**, **Paint Bucket** and **Gradient Tool** by pressing **Shift+G**

Comment: Hi Edwin. I don't mean to be rude, but googling 'change tools Photoshop' yields in excess of 9 **million** results, the first one containing your answer. I'd friendly like to advice you to do some research before asking a basic UI question like this. Thanks for understanding!

Comment: also if you google "paint bucket photoshop CC" there are 288 **thousand** answers containing the answer

Comment: I had the same problem, so you are not alone. Maybe it is easy to google it Vincent, but sometimes it is easier to ask a forum than know which of the 288 thousand answers that is right... If you think you are rude, then dont write anything. Btw. I got it back again when i changed from 3D to essentials in the upper right corner.

Comment: I did Google it, and this question was the only result that gave me the right answer. Everything else was outdated or not relevant, so I'm glad Edwin asked it.

Answer (score 8):

It's a little hidden now, but you can find the good ol' bucket tool under the "Edit Toolbar" icon ···

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In the upper right corner, switch from 3D workspace to essentials.

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot to show what you mean.  Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 2):

You can change between tools like Paint Bucket and Material Drop tool by pressing SHIFT + G

Answer (score -1):

(Sorry I can't comment on the post by Joe - 'In the upper right corner, switch from 3D workspace to essentials.')

I think this answer is most relevant because I had the same issue and SHIFT+G was not working.  For some reason my workspace also shifted to 3D Workspace and despite using Photoshop for years (and knowing all the keyboard shortcuts), I could not get to the paint bucket Also click-and-hold on the Material Drop Bucket did not provide other options as expected (gradient, paint bucket, etc) - UNTIL I changed the workspace to Essentials. So thumbs up to Joe.

Edit Toolbar also helped to add the "Paint Bucket tool" - but it is not clear why Adobe chose this behavior.

Thx.

[image: Toolbar when the 3D workspace is active]

Answer (score -2):

I also had the same problem, been using it for years and shift-G didn't work.  None of the answers on google fixed this (why is there always someone who doesn't know the answer who says look on google?).  It was switching from 3D to essentials on the right upper pull-down which fixed it.  Don't know how it got into 3D.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!